# how to remove a specific value from list

Tags: python

need a little help;
Having the following list of dicts:

```
[{'Nome': 'sapo', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}, {'Nome': 'ivone', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}]
```

how can i remove only one of those 3;
to have for example :

```
[{'Nome': 'sapo', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 2]}, {'Nome': 'ivone', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}]
```

my code right now:

```
            if TamanhoPeça in jogador_peca[1]['pecaespeciais']:
                jogador_peca[1]['pecaespeciais'].remove(TamanhoPeça)
```

TamanhoPeça is the number to be removed
right now when i run the code it show like:

```
[{'Nome': 'sapo', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 2]}, {'Nome': 'ivone', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 2]}]
```

thank you

Comment: Do you mention somewhere Nome value? I think, because of Nome field you remove for all items the second element

Comment: true, i disn´t mention in anywhere, i will try that , ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code in such a state that it will run.  It seems to do what you require:

```
TamanhoPeça = 3
jogador_peca = [{'Nome': 'sapo', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}, {'Nome': 'ivone', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}]
if TamanhoPeça in jogador_peca[1]['pecaespeciais']:
    jogador_peca[1]['pecaespeciais'].remove(TamanhoPeça)
print(jogador_peca)
```

Result:

```
[{'Nome': 'sapo', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 3, 2]}, {'Nome': 'ivone', 'pecaespeciais': [3, 2]}]
```

It seems to me that it is already removing only one one of the '3' values.  It's removing from the second item because of the `[1]` in your `remove` expression.

If you run this line and have a `3` removed from both lists then you must have a single list `[3, 3, 2]` that exists just once and is referenced twice in your data structure.

Comment: i was using a single list for both; had separate lists to do it!
Thank you